# English Language Textbook Made by Artscroll

Tags: jewish-books, artscroll, secular-culture

When I was a kid we used an English literacy reader that was rumored to have been secretly produced by Artscroll under a different name in order to have a "tznius" textbook. Has anyone else ever heard of this and would know what it was called?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mi Yodeya. Can you confirm what you mean by a "textbook"? That in my mind means some sort of study course book, but if so I can't understand the question, so perhaps others might also not know what you mean. Hopefully that will help you get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Are you refering to Mosdos Press?

Comment: There is an English literacy reader that is used in many frum schools and the rumor is that it was secretly published by Artscroll. Nowhere on the book did it say Artscroll or Mosdos

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yehuda and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: https://www.artscroll.com/Categories/TWP.html

Comment: https://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2006/03/rabbi-scroll-textword.html

Comment: https://curiousjew.blogspot.com/2006/03/textword-abridgements-and-false.html